# expected primary expression before 'bool'

Tags: c++

My program says "error: expected primary-expression before 'bool'" on the function call `repeatOrNot (bool);` under the main function. Why is this?

```
bool fiveOrNot(); 
void repeatOrNot (bool);

int main()
{
    fiveOrNot();
    repeatOrNot (bool);

    return 0;
}

bool fiveorNot()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter any number except for 5.\n";
    cin >> number;

    if(number == 5)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void repeatOrNot(bool repeat)
{
    if(repeat == true)
        fiveorNot();
    else
        cout << ":(\n";
}
```

Comment: You need a value of type `bool` in your call to `repeatOrNot`. Writing the type name makes no sense. Did you mean `repeatOrNot(fiveOrNot())`?

Comment: Inside `repeatOrNot`, you don't need to write `if (repeat == true)`, just `if(repeat)`. Both will evaluate to true if `repeat` is true.

Answer (score 4):

In C++. there are so-called *formal parameters* and *actual parameters*. When you are defining a function, you are dealing with formal parameters, meaning you should only specify a type of the parameter, and (if you want to) give it some meaningfull name

```
void repeatOrNot(bool repeat)//<----"repeat" is a formal parameter. 
//You are not passing anything to the function, 
//you are just telling the compiler that this function accepts one argument 
//of a bool type.
{
    if(repeat == true)
        fiveorNot();
    else
        cout << ":(\n";
}
```

However, when you are calling a function, you need to pass it an actual parameter, i.e. some variable of a correct type. In your case, you probably meant to pass the result of a call to `fiveOrNot` function. You can do it like this:

```
bool isFive = fiveOrNot();
repeatOrNot (isFive);//<---This is an actual parameter.
//here you are really passing a variable to your function.
```

or like this:

```
repeatOrNot(fiveOrNot());//<--the result of the execution of "fiveOrNot" will be passed into "repeatOrNot"
```